# TableView height is not adopting dynamic size

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview, nslayoutconstraint

I have table view in which I have another table view. Actually I make dynamic section with cells coming from backend.

The problem is that is not showing the last cell.

Here is the main table view height setting:

[image]

//This code is in first view controller updating table view height

```
override func updateViewConstraints() {
    tableViewHieght.constant = tableView.contentSize.height
    super.updateViewConstraints()
}

override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) 
{
    tableView.layer.removeAllAnimations()
    tableViewHieght.constant = tableView.contentSize.height
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
        self.updateViewConstraints()
    }
}
```

Add picture for more clarification

I don't know what I should do for second table view that is in cell so it adopt the dynamic size.

The actual output:

[image]

I work on it and i realised the problem is with first table view row height i inspect the constraint and all settings that is necessary for making it dynamic but still it not growing i did a lil hack but i really want to do it with tableview.automatic dimension
// this is first table view cell in that cells every cell contain a label and a table view a second one which contain some label that making a format like section and cells In second table view I used Table view.automatic dimension

[image]

Comment: I was working on that problem and i found that problem is with main table view height for row at indexpath func I'm returning automatic dimension but strangly it's not getting the space even i did the layout constriant according to the requirements for making it auto resizeable. can anyone help me witth this

Comment: It's not clear from your images what parts are what... You need to either **simplify** your structure, so it's clear what your layout is, or - probably better - put together enough code for a [mre].

Comment: Please check now

Comment: Actually the problem is when i put table view in another table view cell tableview.automaticdimension not working properly

Comment: As a general rule, it's not a good idea to use a tableView as a subview of a tableViewCell... The likely problem you are running into is that the "outer" table view lays out its cells, and *then* your cell-table-view lays out its cells... but does not communicate to the outer table view that the height is now different. It is still not clear what your view structure is though --- when you post here, try to provide complete details about what you are doing. Does this look correct? https://i.stack.imgur.com/KY3PQ.png